# (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql

Below is the database that I'm trying to implement:-

```
CREATE DATABASE Cinema;
USE Cinema;

-- Person Supertype
CREATE TABLE Person (
    ID INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Age TINYINT(120) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

-- Customer Subtype
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    Customer_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Type enum('Member','Adult','Student','Child'),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Customer_ID) REFERENCES Person(ID)
);

-- Staff Subtype
CREATE TABLE Staff (
    Staff_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    SalaryPerMonth DECIMAL(6,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(Staff_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Staff_ID) REFERENCES Person(ID)
);

--Booking enitity
CREATE TABLE Booking (
    Booking_ID INT(3) NOT NULL,
    Price DECIMAL(3,2),
    TicketQuantity INT(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(Booking_ID)
);

--Customer_Booking relationship
CREATE TABLE Customer_Booking (
    Customer_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Booking_ID INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID, Booking_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Booking_ID) REFERENCES Booking(Booking_ID)
);
```

The error appears when I enter the above table.

Comment: @Dinidu Thank you very much, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your booking_id columns in both **customer_booking** and **booking** tables are not equal. One is **UNSIGNED** but other one is not. So you can use the following table creation script for "**customer_booking**" table

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Booking (
    Customer_ID INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Booking_ID INT(3)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID, Booking_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Booking_ID) REFERENCES Booking(Booking_ID)
);
```

Or

if you want **booking_id** to be **unsigned** then correct it in the **booking** table creation script.